# Separar datos de un name=algo[] en un select múltiple dentro de un foreach

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tengo el siguiente caso: un select múltiple dentro de un foreach para poder repetir varias veces ese campo en el formulario.
Lo que sucede es que sí selecciono el select 1 rojo y azul, y en el select 2 selecciono verde.
El array que se envía al controlador queda como: array [rojo, azul, verde], no hay forma de identificar que grupo de datos pertenece a que select. Intente colocar así: level [{{$contador}}][] pero igual me guarda todos los datos de ésta forma: level:{contador:{rojo, azul, verde}}.
Dejo aquí el código.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Los selects no deberían tener el mismo name.

Comment: con lo que me dijo @VictoriaRuiz y con la idea que tenia desde hace rato en la cabeza solucioné concatenando una variable tanto al name del array en el formulario como en el request del controlador.. quedando asi en el formulario: name="level{{$count}}[]" y asi en el controlador: ${"level".$count} = implode(",", $request->{"level".$count}); de esta forma obtengo tantos request como array se envien y de paso los convierto a string para guardarlos mas facil.

Answer (score 0):

si quieres identificar cada select puedes enviarlo como un array bidimensional

por ejemplo

```
@foreach($array as $key => $a){
 <select name="level[][{{$key}}]"></select> 
@}
```

Answer (score 0):

El atributo `name=" "` esta mal asignado. Mira el siguiente ejemplo:

```
<select name="color1">
    <option value="rojo">Rojo</option>
    <option value="azul">Azul</option>
    <option value"verde">Verde</option>
</select>
```

El atributo `name=" "`es el nombre de la variable que contendrá la selección que hagas dentro de este por lo tanto dependiendo de lo que elijas el formulario mandara lo siguiente contenido en la variable `color1`:

- `color1=rojo`
- `color1=azul`
- `color1=verde`

Si despues de esto vuelves a creas otro select con el mismo `name` estos acabaran colisionando y dependiendo del navegador daran respuestas diferentes.

Por lo tanto lo que necesitas es que el siguiente select tenga otro `name=" "` diciendole de esta forma "*la siguiente seleccion guardalo con otro nombre*"

```
<select name="color1">
    <option value="rojo">Rojo</option>
    <option value="azul">Azul</option>
    <option value"verde">Verde</option>
</select>
<select name="color2">
    <option value="rojo">Rojo</option>
    <option value="azul">Azul</option>
    <option value"verde">Verde</option>
</select>
```

De esta forma el  `color1` tendra una valor y `color2` otro y los select no colisionaran entre si.